# Is there a small easel or book butler for an ereader?

Tags: ebook-readers

Is there something like a small easel or book butler to be used with an ereader?
I don't like the way the device feels when I hold it.  I like holding a book, and I like hardcover books where the pages lie flat nicely.

Comment: I read your question twice and honestly I can't understand what you are talking about. Can you please try to be clearer?

Comment: @Anthon - Thanks for the assistance.  By the way, I think you mean "thinking out loud."  ("Loud thinking" might be understood as a criticism -- but I didn't take it that way, I figured out what you meant.)

Comment: @aparente001 Yeah, that was it.

Comment: @Sekhemty - I've split my question up into two separate questions, and added an image to try to show what the wrapping problem looks like: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7370/9925  I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mini easels (like [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XDHLJF9) from Amazon), I have seen them in all kinds of different sizes in shops catering for artists (in Germany).

Given that your ebook is rigid (all that I know are), you can easily make such a book butler by using a 20mm thick block of wood, the size of your ebook reader, and routing a slot slightly wider than your readers thickness about 2/3 deep.
If you don't have a router, you can use three 6mm pieces of wood, and from two cut off a 15mm strip and from the rest the thickness of your reader + plus a bit, then glue the 4 pieces so created on top of the full size base

```
###   #######################
###   #######################
#############################
```

You put the ebook with the front to the left, and the ebook leaning like this: `/`.

Make sure the "groove" is not to deep to cover any buttons that might be at the bottom of your reader. While it might be OK to take it out when you want to switch it off, doing so for every page turn is probably not what you want.

Comment: I made an easel for my laptop (out of cardboard, using an Instructable), and I use it on a small shelf; but I'm not sure I'm going to be happy with an ereader even with an easel.  I'm so used to holding a book in my hands!

Comment: I am used to that as well. And since I like to read without glasses, I have to use a slightly larger font, which means flipping pages more often.

Comment: can you take a look at my other question, please?  https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7370/9925