# Alternative to Kobo to solve line wrapping problem

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, kobo, formatting

I was given a Kobo as a gift.  I like the idea of reading a book on an electronic device because I'd like to be able to click and see a definition of a word that I'm not familiar with, rather than going to look for the dictionary.

However, I'm unhappy with the width of the device.  Unless I make the font very small, every line is getting wrapped/carried to the next line.  Example:

[image: line wrapping]

I suppose I either need a format of book that will allow for fluid display of the text, or I need a larger device.

I would like to read pdfs as well as books.  I don't like two-column pdfs, where I have to page-down to follow the whole left-hand column, and then jump up to the right-hand column.

Answer (score 2):

I also own a Kobo ereader.

From what I can see, the rather messy output that you get is probably caused by a badly formatted ebook file, being it `.pdf` or `.epub`. It is just a supposition, but I really think that this layout is not your ereader fault. If this is really the case, there is not much you can do about it, other than trying to find a better version of the file.

You can do a quick test by downloading a properly formatted ebook file (i.e. [this freely available version of Dracula](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=185692)) and seeing if you keep having this problem.

Ereaders are mainly intended to be used with reflowable text ebook formats, like `.azw` for Amazon Kindle and `.epub` for the rest of the world; when acquired from legitimate sources, they are usually properly formatted.
Even if ereaders support the `.pdf` format, it is mainly for the sake of completeness, it is a format mainly used for fixed layout pages and is not really suited to be read from a small screen; whenever you can you should rely on the above-mentioned formats.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have any tips for finding books in the correct formats, and/or for converting?  But maybe I need to write or look for a separate question....

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like an improperly formatted eBook than a problem with your ereader's screen size.  It looks as if there's a hard paragraph break or line return after every line of text in the file.  If the file is not DRM protected, you may want to consider using Calibre to convert/reformat the file and use [it heuristic processing feature](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#heuristic-processing) to unwrap the lines.